# Intel wireless controller 8260 unclaimed on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, 15.10, firmware

After I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a new Thinkpad carbon, I had to add the two kernel parameters `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` and `nolapic` to get Ubuntu working. The installation seems to be fine, but the wifi controller won't work.

Here is the output of `lshw -C network`, `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1100000-f1101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 54:ee:75:90:ec:ac
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.5-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:11 memory:f1300000-f131ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enx00eb4e68052d
       serial: 00:eb:4e:68:05:2d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.08.1 (2015/07/28) duplex=full ip=192.168.178.87 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
fabian@PizCavradi:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0130]
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a802] (rev 01)
fabian@PizCavradi:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.598435] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.681639] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: pci_enable_msi failed(0Xffffffda)
[    2.747142] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: invalid TLV len: 3180/4294967295
[    2.747259] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-14.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.749072] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v15, firmware is v421399808.
[    2.749672] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-12.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.749674] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-8000C-12.ucode' failed.
[    2.749847] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-11.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.749849] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-8000C-11.ucode' failed.
[    2.749856] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-10.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.749857] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-8000C-10.ucode' failed.
[    2.749858] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    2.751430] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
```

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi` doesn't return anything and the ethernet connection works fine. So it seems like there is a problem with the firmware for my wifi controller. I already did some updates and tried suggestions from other posts but nothing was successful.

So does anyone has a solution for my problem? Many thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for your responses! `uname -a` returns

```
Linux PizCavradi 4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 10 22:13:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The wireless controller is not unclaimed anymore, but it still won't work. The output of `dmesg | grep iwl` now is

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.690951] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.691504] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: pci_enable_msi failed(0Xffffffda)
[    2.820257] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.195093.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.824280] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.863303] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    2.867954] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.868894] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.874298] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    9.574405] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    9.574406] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    9.574408] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    9.574875] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    9.574895] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

Interestingly, when I run `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` and then `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` my notebook freezes and I have to press the power button until it switches off. After restarting, `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` works.

Comment: Please add output of `uname -a` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the latest firmware. You can install it by opening a terminal and doing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd iwlwifi-firmware/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-8000*  /lib/firmware
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Your wireless should be working. It might take a reboot, however.

If this firmware is ineffective, please try:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot.

I suggest we temporarily try a newer version of the driver. Please download this file to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot. If this and the firmware are effective, I will suggest that we install an entire 4.4.6 kernel.

NOTE: This assumes that your install is English; if not, and if Desktop is named something different, substitute above. For example:

```
cd ~/Escritorio/backports-4.4.2-1
```

Let's try even newer firmware files:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
```

Reboot. Then paste again:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Reviewing your last paste, I am very concerned about this:

> [    2.678204] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: pci_enable_msi failed(0Xffffffda)

I think this bug report is related: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114101 It suggests adding a boot option *irqpoll*.

Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Find the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add irqpoll to the end.  it should result in something like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash irqpoll"
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Now do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and show us again:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: Op has a non-standard kernel. Firmware 13 has a wrong API for it. It can be fixed by changing a kernel, or by installation of a newer firmware from that github or from `linux-firmware` for xenial.

Comment: Okay, now the wifi controller is not unclaimed anymore. However, it is still not working. I posted the new output of `dmesg | grep iwl` in a new answer, down here.

Comment: Is this after installing the first firmware file, from github, or the second, by installing linux-firmware? If you have lengthy logs to post, paste them here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to ask ubuntu...I will use paste.ubuntu.com in future! This is after installing the firmware from github. I think the linux-firmware didn't change it at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 As far as I can tell, the firmware blobs common to both linux-firmware and github, namely -13 and -16, are identical. Also, 4.2.0-34 is not a non-standard kernel.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: 13 and 16 are not identical, they have different API. The kernel looks OK.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also didn't work. I get the same error message as before.

Comment: Please run these commands and paste them as I outlined above. Give us the link. `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 8000`

Comment: Alright, here is the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15568179/

Comment: Please see a further edit in a few moments.

Comment: Again, this did not change much: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15574830/. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Please see a further edit in a few minutes.

Comment: It didn't change the output of `dmesg | grep iwl` much (http://paste.ubuntu.com/15576846), but wifi works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe I was a bit hasty. It turned out that `irqpoll` as kernel parameter often makes my installation to freeze at startup. I. e. when I enter my password, just before I reach the desktop. Any solutions for that?